# Is Ruby's `BasicObject.new` undocumented?

Tags: ruby, object, methods

I want to read the Ruby documentation for the `new` method, as in:

```
class Dog
end

fido = Dog.new("Fido")
```

but tracing through the Ruby docs leads me to [this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/BasicObject.html#method-c-new):

> `new()`
>
> Not documented

Am I looking in the wrong place, or is one of the most ubiquitous methods actually undocumented?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at `Dog.new("Fido")`,I am sure you are looking for [`Class#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Class.html#method-i-new),not the `BasicObject#new`. Because your `Dog` class is an instance of `Class`.

```
class Dog
    #code
end
Dog.instance_of? Class # => true
```

More examples :

```
Foo = Class.new # Class::new is called
Foo.instance_of? Class # => true
foo = Foo.new # Class#new is called
foo.instance_of? Foo   # => true
```

Comment: You're linking to `Class::new`